# DBA/SQL - Structuring DB for multiple price information for the same product

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to structure a data base for a Marketplace Ecommerce. The idea is to have multiple sellers selling **the same products** on the WebSite, so the customer can choose which seller he want.

I'm stuck on the DB strategy. What is the best practice to structure it? I was thinking in the logic below:

[image]

This logic will work and will be easy to manipulate but will multiply my DB lines per the quantity of sellers that sell the products. I think it'll become to heavy.

Any idea? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use one table for products, one table for sellers, and one table for a many-to-many relationship between product and sellers, that will include the stoke amount:

```
tblProduct
----------
product_Id 
product_Name 
... other product related columns

tblSeller
---------
Seller_Id
Seller_Name
... other seller related columns

tblStock
--------
Stock_Product_Id
Stock_Seller_Id
Stock_Amount
```

Comment: Hi Zohar. Thx for the answer.
I'm just worried with the size of the "tblStock" because for which each product there will be N lines.

Example: I've 1k products and 5 sellers that sells this products. This way I'll have 5k lines at the "tblStock".

I understand that is the best way to do this, but I'm concerned only with the table size

Comment: for a table of 3 integers, even 30 million records is not that big.

Comment: Nice. I'll try this method. Thx Zohar